# Adding NSMutableArray to another from a loop seems to create duplicates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, loops, nsmutablearray

I'm parsing through an `NSDictionary` of json-encoded events and placing them into a two-dimensional `NSMutableArray` based on their month -- for display in a sectioned table view.

Since I am adding items to an array and then placing that array in an array (`event_container`) in a loop, `event_container` shows the correct number of arrays, however, they all appear to be duplicates of the last iteration, so all of the contents of `event_container` are the same array.

I believe this is because it's a pointer and/or not being released. I'm unsure of an appropriate way around this or possibly even a better solution. I'm using ARC.

```
int month = 0;
int current_month = 0;
int counter = 0;

event_container = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

temp_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for (NSDictionary *result in results)
{

    NCEvent *anEvent = [[NCEvent alloc] init];

    anEvent.title = [result objectForKey:@"title"];
    anEvent.startdate = [result objectForKey:@"startdate"];
    anEvent.enddate = [result objectForKey:@"enddate"];

    NSDateFormatter *importDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [importDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-M-d H:m:ss"];
    anEvent.dateStart = [importDate dateFromString:anEvent.startdate];
    anEvent.dateEnd = [importDate dateFromString: anEvent.enddate];

    NSDateFormatter *exportDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [exportDate setDateFormat:@"d"];
    anEvent.text_date = [exportDate stringFromDate: anEvent.dateStart];

    NSDateFormatter *exportMon = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [exportMon setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
    anEvent.text_mon = [exportMon stringFromDate: anEvent.dateStart];

    NSDateFormatter *monthInt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [monthInt setDateFormat:@"M"];
    month = [[monthInt stringFromDate: anEvent.dateStart] intValue];

    if(counter == 1){                           //first month
        current_month = month;
        NSLog(@"I'm the first month: %i", month); 
        [temp_array addObject:anEvent];

    }
    else if(month > current_month){             //new month
        NSLog(@"This is a new month");                    
        current_month = month;

        //add the events array to events container and reset the events array
        [self.event_container addObject: temp_array];

        [temp_array removeAllObjects];

        [temp_array addObject:anEvent];

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Same Month");                   //same month
        [temp_array addObject:anEvent];


    }

    NSLog(@"Event month integer: %i", month);

    anEvent = nil;

    counter++;

}
```

Those arrays are declared as properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *event_container;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *temp_array;
```

Comment: Is this whole chunk of code inside a loop too?

Comment: no, thats the only loop involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line:

```
[self.event_container addObject: temp_array];
```

You are always adding the same instance `temp_array` to `self.event_container`. This is why you see the same array duplicated many times.

You can solve this by doing the following for example:

-Add the following before your for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    [event_container addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
}
for (NSDictionary *result in results)
...
```

-Remove

```
if(counter == 1){                           //first month
     current_month = month;
     NSLog(@"I'm the first month: %i", month); 
     [temp_array addObject:anEvent];
}
```

-and change the code that comes after that into :

```
tmp_array = [event_container objectAtIndex:month];
[temp_array addObject:anEvent];
```

Comment: yeah, this makes total sense... however, do you have any suggestions if i didn't know the total number of months beforehand? could i delete empty arrays added to the event_container after the loop?

Comment: i ended up added the objects on the fly as needed... works perfect, thank you so much

Comment: @jaytr0n Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicions about the array being a pointer is basically correct. The problem is that your `temp_array` isn't so temporary -- it's in fact the same array object every time through your loop.

You're creating it outside the loop, and whenever you send it `addObject:` or `removeAllObjects`, it's affecting the stuff that you've already put in there.

The key part, though, is that when you add the `temp_array` to `event_container`, it's the exact same object. It's not copied; the `event_container` array just gets a pointer to `temp_array`. When you add it again, it's the same thing. Since `event_container` just holds a whole bunch of pointers, you end up looking at the same object when you inspect it.

That's what's happening. To solve this, you need to create a separate array for each month; I think that [sch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9317587/603977) will work for you.

A quick demonstration:

```
NSMutableArray * container = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray * temp = [NSMutableArray array];

int i;
for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
    [temp addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    [container addObject:temp];    // Doesn't copy; just adds pointer to temp
    [temp removeAllObjects];
}
// Inspecting container now, we find that it has five arrays, all empty.
NSLog(@"%@", container);
```

Comment: If he does that, he will end up with as much arrays as **results.count**. I don't think this is what he wants to do.

Comment: Oh, yup, I see what you mean.

Comment: when I try this method, I only get the last result for that particular month as it creates a new array every time the loop goes through and only adds it to the container array as it hits a new month

Comment: @jaytr0n: I misunderstood what you were doing. See sch's answer; it should work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

temp_array is a pointer type (like all objects in objective c). Therefore, with this call:

`[self.event_container addObject: temp_array];`

...you are adding a pointer to that object to event_container. You are not creating a new array, merely adding multiple pointers to the same object. What you most likely want to do is add a (pointer to a) copy of the object, like this:

`[self.event_container addObject: [temp_array mutableCopy]];`

Comment: Except, that if you use `[temp_array mutableCopy]` you are leaking memory. You are losing a reference to an object that you own (the result of the `-mutableCopy`).

Comment: Although this doesn't really matter with ARC, you are right, the other proposed solutions are probably better.